# Asp.net Web.config Returns null after Publishing my application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

After i publish my web.config i get null reference to all the code that uses the webconfig.
What could be happening?
I checked my web.config property and its set to Embedded Resource. Is this how its supposed to be.
Help people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of my applications have the `web.config` file with a Build Action of `Content` and not `Embedded Resource`.  Try changing this and see if that helps.

Comment: ok when i change it to conent every thing works ok..But why do i need the web.Release.config and we.Debug.config files anyway??

Comment: These files are merged into the web.config file.  You can add settings into your Debug.config file that you wouldn't want in the final release version.

Comment: @lafama: you can find out more information here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

Comment: ok i thought that the web.config file becomes embedded then when u need to change anything you in the default web.config, one can like update the we.release.config file with the respective parameters

Answer (score 1):

It should be set to Content (this is the default by the way).